# Django custom template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I have defined a custom template tag, in a file called `custom_tags.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def currencysymbol():
    if settings.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en-gb':
        return '£'
    else:
        return 'unknown'
```

Which is referenced in a template:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
{{ currencysymbol }}
```

The problem, is that it doesn't render. It is certainly loading the library, as I modified the load to tag to `{% load foo %}` and it correctly told me that this library does not exist, and listed 'custom_tags' as one of the available options.

However, `{{ currencysymbol }}` renders to nothing at all. To ensure that it wasn't my function, I modified it to simply return a string (without the if/else and the settings. stuff), but it still rendered nothing.

I believe that I have followed the docs, so I'm not sure what's happening. The page renders without errors, but my tag is simply not there.

Comment: The tag is `{% currencysymbol %}` with `{% .. %}`, not `{{ .. }}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a tag, so that means you should use it like:

```
{% currencysymbol %}
```

So with the `{% .. %}` brackets, *not*:

```
{{ currencysymbol }}
```

The `{{ .. }}` is used for *variables*.